# Create onmouseover/onmouseout functions dynamically with javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, onmouseover, onmouseout

So here is an example of the function I need to replicate:

```
document.getElementById('img1').onmouseover = function() {
    document.getElementById('img1').style.width = expandTo + '%';

    expandCompensate(1);
}

document.getElementById('img1').onmouseout = function() {
    expandReset();
}
```

The situation is that I have a `for` loop creating some `div` elements, and the number of them is dynamic.  As of right now, I have it creating 4 div elements, so I created 4 iterations of the above functions for `img1`, `img2`, `img3` and `img4`.  But what I would like to do is to have the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` functions created dynamically based on how many `div` elements I've decided to create (based on a variable).

Is there any way to do this?  Here is all the code for context (it's not much), there are comments in the JS with explanations for everything.  The part I'm trying to automate is at the bottom:

https://jsfiddle.net/4w0714su/3/

And here is the working example for context of what I'm trying to achieve:

http://www.ericsartor.ca/imgwide

FYI: The image is I picked were random, I just needed high res images.  Just doing this for practice!  Thanks to anyone that can help me figure this out!

Comment: What is this `imgClasses` that you have in your code?

Comment: Oh sorry, ignore that.  I was using that to count how many divs I had written into the HTML before I did that using the JS.  I was using the `length` selector to count all the `imgPane` classes.  Sorry about that, thought I got rid of that :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand your code very well, but I'll answer particularly what you're asking.

You can achieve what you want by doing a loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  document.getElementById('img' + i).onmouseover = function() {
    this.style.width = expandTo + '%';
    expandCompensate(Number(this.id.replace('img', '')));
  };

  document.getElementById('img' + i).onmouseout = function() {
    expandReset();
  }
}
```

Note: you can't use the `i` variable inside the event handlers' functions, because it will always be `4`, since it will finish the loop, and will never be changed again.

---

Another way of doing that is by using an [IIFE (Immediately-invoked function expression)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjABahUKEwi2oKW4haXIAhWBkJAKHcATBNM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FImmediately-invoked_function_expression&usg=AFQjCNHmjdPE2BVJrAZaYZUMosX0APzCiQ&sig2=6-TVWK-lOSccT8Z1Qxyi9Q), e.g:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  (function(n) {
    document.getElementById('img' + n).onmouseover = function() {
      this.style.width = expandTo + '%';
      expandCompensate(n);
    };

    document.getElementById('img' + n).onmouseout = function() {
      expandReset();
    }
  })(i);
}
```

Doing that, you're passing to a function the current `i` value, so in that scope, the value of `n` will be a different one for each execution, e.g `0`, `1`, `2` and `3`.

> An immediately-invoked function expression (or IIFE, pronounced
>   "iffy") is a JavaScript design pattern which produces a lexical scope
>   using JavaScript's function scoping.

Comment: Are there any particular advantages/disadvantages to either method?

Comment: So the first method definitely works (thanks very much!), just a couple questions.I don't fully understand why you can't use the `i` variable inside the event handler...by my logic, if it can be used to identify the element, why can't it be used inside the function? Also, I've been using `parseInt` to do what you did there with `Number()`.  Is `Number()` generally a better idea?

Comment: The event handler runs  asynchronously, outside the logic of your for loop, and after the loop has finished executing.  At that point, i will have the value it had when the loop finished running - i.e. 4.

Answer (score 0):

> This could be achieved by iterating all those `DOM` elements and binding events in a `loop`.
>
> As we bind events in `loop`, and event `callback` is being executed later when loop would be iterated completely, we need to maintaing the value of current iteration using `CLOSURE`.

Try this snippet:

```js
var pageHeight = document.getElementById('findBottom').getBoundingClientRect().bottom,
  numOfPics = 4; //the number of div elements to create

//creates the div elements within a container div in the HTML document
for (var i = 1; i <= numOfPics; i++) {
  document.getElementById('imgContain').innerHTML += '<div id="img' + i + '" class="imgPane"></div>';
}

//used to resize all divs if the window changes size
window.onresize = function() {
  pageHeight = document.getElementById('findBottom').getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
  for (var i = 1; i <= imgClasses.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('img' + i).style.height = pageHeight + 'px';
  }
  for (var i = 1; i <= imgClasses.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('img' + i).style.width = 100 / imgClasses.length + '%';
  }
};

//sets the height of each div to be the mximum height of the page (without scrolling)
for (var i = 1; i <= numOfPics; i++) {
  document.getElementById('img' + i).style.height = pageHeight + 'px';
}

//makes all the divs equal percentage widths
for (var i = 1; i <= numOfPics; i++) {
  document.getElementById('img' + i).style.width = 100 / numOfPics + '%';
}

//the percentage of the page the hovered image will expand to
var expandTo = 40;

//function for when an image is hovered over
function expandCompensate(whichImg) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= numOfPics; i++) {
    if (i != whichImg)
      document.getElementById('img' + i).style.width = (100 - expandTo) / (numOfPics - 1) + '%';
  }
}

//function for when the hovered image is left to reset the widths
function expandReset() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= numOfPics; i++) {
      document.getElementById('img' + i).style.width = 100 / numOfPics + '%';
    }
  }
  (function bindEvents() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= numOfPics; i++) {
      document.getElementById('img' + i).onmouseover = (function(i) {
        return function() {
          document.getElementById('img' + i).style.width = expandTo + '%';
          expandCompensate(i);
        }
      })(i);

      document.getElementById('img' + i).onmouseout = function() {
        expandReset();
      };
    }
  })();
```

```css
body,
p,
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {} #findBottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.imgPane {
  float: left;
  background-position: center;
  transition: width 0.25s;
}
#img1 {
  background-image: url('http://www.ericsartor.ca/imgwide/img//1.jpg');
}
#img2 {
  background-image: url('http://www.ericsartor.ca/imgwide/img//2.jpg');
}
#img3 {
  background-image: url('http://www.ericsartor.ca/imgwide/img//3.jpg');
}
#img4 {
  background-image: url('http://www.ericsartor.ca/imgwide/img//4.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div id="imgContain"></div>

<!-- ABSOLUTE ELEMENTS -->
<div id="findBottom"></div>
<!-- ABSOLUTE ELEMENTS -->
```